# ImageMagick identify returns ENOENT error

Tags: node.js, webdriver, imagemagick, webdriver-io

Trying to get `ImageMagick` working within a `WebdriverIO` visual regression test, but am getting the below error. I've verified `ImageMagick` is installed and available on path (`$ magick -version` returns correctly), am able to call other functions, but identify does not work.

Pretty sure the promise rejection is just a result of `ImageMagick` not returning an image, so obviously it would be undefined when trying to check height.

I'm on Windows, latest NodeJs, latest WebdriverIO.

Any advice would be great.

> { Error: spawn magick identify ENOENT
>           at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
>           at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
>           at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
>           at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
>           at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
>         code: 'ENOENT',
>         errno: 'ENOENT',
>         syscall: 'spawn magick identify',
>         path: 'magick identify',
>         spawnargs:
>          [ '-format',
>            '%m %z %w %h %b %x %y %f',
>            './test/screenshots/Amazon/Home/navbar.diff.png' ],
>         cmd: 'magick identify -format %m %z %w %h %b %x %y %f ./test/screenshots/Amazon/Home/navbar.diff.png' }
>       no stdout
>       F
>
> ```
> 0 passing (19.70s)
> 1 failing
>
> Promise was rejected with the following reason: TypeError: Cannot read property 'height' of undefined
> running chrome
> Error: Promise was rejected with the following reason: TypeError: Cannot read property 'height' of undefined
> ```

Comment: Wouldn't the command be `identify` not `magick identify`?

Comment: Should be, but identify doesn't work - command not found. Magick identify works fine when I run a cli command, but not as part of the test